# What are the linear maps which preserve the time-like cone?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, mathematical-physics, inertial-frames, causality

I'm looking at the set of time-like vectors:

$$\mathcal{T}_+ = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mbox{ s.t. } x^T \eta x \geq 0 \:, x^0\geq 0\} ,$$ where $\eta = \mbox{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$.

I want to be able to characterize the set of linear operators that preserve this set:
$$\mathcal{V} = \{L\in M(4,\mathbb{R}) \mbox{ s.t. } L x \in \cal T_+\,, \forall x \in \cal T_+\}.$$
Clearly $L$ must satisfy
$$x^T L^T \eta L x \geq 0\:,  (Lx)^0\geq 0 \:\:\forall x \in \mathcal{T}_+\:.$$

Is $\mathcal{V}$ convex? It's clear that the orthochronous Lorentz transformations preserve $\mathcal{T}_+$, since $x^T \Lambda \eta \Lambda^T x = x^T \eta x$. Do these form the boundary of $\mathcal{V}$?

A clue: I know that $\mathcal{T}_+$ is convex.

Comment: Concerning the boundary of $\mathcal{V}$, I think some clues can be found in sections 8 and 9 of this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0212
I have yet to completely decipher it though.

Answer (score 7):

Replacing $GL(4, \mathbb R)$ with $M(4, \mathbb R)$ we have
$${\cal V}:= \{M \in M(4, \mathbb R)\:|\: \mbox{if $x\in {\cal T}_+$, then $Mx \in {\cal T}_+$}\}\tag{1}\:,$$
where
$${\cal T}_+ := \{x \in \mathbb R^4 \:|\: x^T\eta x \geq 0\:, x^0 \geq 0\}$$
so that we can equivalently restate the given definition as
$${\cal V}:=$$ $$\{M \in M(4, \mathbb R)\:|\: \mbox{ $x^T\eta x \geq 0$,  $x^0 \geq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^TM^T\eta Mx \geq 0$, $(Mx)^0 \geq 0$}\}\tag{2}\:.$$

**Proposition**.
*With the given definition of $\cal V$, it turns out to be a **closed** **convex** **cone** of the real vector space $M(4,\mathbb R)$.*

PROOF.
The set is trivially a cone, because, if $M \in \cal V$, then $\lambda M \in \cal V$ in view of the given definition for $\lambda \geq 0$.
Let us establish that it is convex, too.
Let  $M, M' \in \cal V$ and $p,q \in [0,1]$ with $p+q=1$. If $x\in {\cal T}_+$, then $Mx$, $M'x \in {\cal T}_+$ by (1). Moreover, as  ${\cal T}_+$ is convex, it also holds $pMx+ qM'x \in  {\cal T}_+$. Using (2), this fact can equivalently be re-written as $$(pMx+ qM'x)^T \eta (pMx+ qM'x) \geq 0\:,$$
that is
$$x^T(pM+ qM')^T \eta (pM+ qM')x \geq 0$$
Similarly, because the left-hand side is sum of two non-negative numbers, $$((pM+qM')x)^0\geq 0\:.$$
Since the found identity hold for every $x\in {\cal T}_+$, looking at (2), we have proved that if $M,M' \in \cal V$ and $p,q \in [0,1]$ with $p+q=1$, then
$pM+qM' \in \cal V$. In other words $\cal V$ is convex.
Let us finally prove that $\cal V$ is closed in the natural topology of $M(4,\mathbb R) \subset \mathbb R^{16}$. If ${\cal V} \ni M_n \to M \in M(4,\mathbb R)$ with respect to the said topology for $n\to +\infty$, and $x^T\eta x \geq 0$, then  $$0\leq x^TM_n^T\eta M_nx \to x^TM^T\eta Mx\geq 0$$ since all involved operations are continuous and $[0,+\infty)$ is closed.
The condition on $x^0$ survives the limit procedure similarly.
(2) implies that $M \in \cal V$. Since $\cal V$ includes all of its limit points, it must be closed.
QED

**ADDENDUM**

Regarding the boundary of $\cal V$, we have $O(3,1)_+ \subset \partial \cal V$. In fact, if $\Lambda \in O(3,1)_+$, then (a)  it belongs to $\cal V$ and (b) there is a *continuous* curve joining $\Lambda$ and some point in $M(4,\mathbb R) \setminus \cal V$. It is $$[1/2,1]\ni \Lambda_\lambda := \lambda \mapsto \mbox{diag}(\lambda, 1, 1, 1) \Lambda\:.$$
For every $\lambda \in [1/2,1)$, $\Lambda_\lambda \not \in \cal V$ because it transforms future-oriented  lightlike vectors into spacelike ones. Summing up, $\Lambda \in \cal V$, but
$\Lambda \not \in Int(\cal V)$. It must be $\Lambda \in \partial \cal V$.

Nevertheless, the same reasoning holds if replacing $\Lambda$ with a pure dilatation transformation $D_z u := z u$ with $z>0$ fixed, for all $u \in \mathbb R^4$. Therfore, as $D_z \not \in O(3,1)_+$, we have that $O(3,1)_+ \neq \partial \cal V$.

Compositions $D_z \Lambda$ certainly belong to $\partial \cal V$. I suspect they are the only elements of that frontier and that (see Qmechanic's answer) the convex hull of the set of those elements coincides to $\cal V$ itself.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. Do you have any clues about my second question (the boundary of $\cal V$)?

Comment: Indeed, every orthochronous Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ stays in the boundary of $\cal V$. This is because, evidently, every small deformation of the form $\Lambda_\lambda :=diag(\lambda,1,1,1) \Lambda$ verifies $\Lambda_\lambda \not \in \cal V$ for $\lambda = 1-\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily small. However it is clear that, for the same reason, the boundary is also made of different transformations like pure (positive) dilatations.

Comment: There is now an ADDENDUM to my answer including details of the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

OP is asking about 3+1 dimensions, but let us here work out the corresponding construction in 1+1 dimensions. The 1+1 dimensional result may be used as a toy model to gain some intuition of what might (or might not) hold in higher dimensions. We use [light-cone coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-cone_coordinates) $x^{\pm}$.

1. The future light-cone is
   $$ {\cal T}_+~=~\{(x^+,x^-)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^{\pm}\geq 0\}.\tag{1}$$
   The set
   $$\begin{align}{\cal V} ~:=~& \{M\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \mid M({\cal T}_+)\subseteq {\cal T}_+\}\cr 
   ~=~&\left\{ \left.\begin{pmatrix}a &b\cr c &d \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \right| a,b,c,d\geq 0 \right\} \end{align}\tag{2}$$
   is the set of [non-negative matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix).
2. The restricted [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) is
   $$ SO^+(1,1)~=~\left\{ \left.\begin{pmatrix}a &0\cr 0 &a^{-1} \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \right| a>0 \right\}.\tag{3} $$
   The [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of $SO^+(1,1)$ is
   $$ {\rm Conv}(SO^+(1,1))~=~\left\{ \left.\begin{pmatrix}a &0\cr 0 &d \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \right| a,d>0, ad\geq 1 \right\}.\tag{4}$$
   The closed [convex cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone) of $SO^+(1,1)$ is the set
   $$ \overline{{\rm Convcone}(SO^+(1,1))}~=~\left\{ \left.\begin{pmatrix}a &0\cr 0 &d \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \right| a,d\geq0,  \right\}\tag{5}$$
   of diagonal matrices with non-negative eigenvalues.
3. The orthochronous Lorentz group is
   $$ O^+(1,1)~=~SO^+(1,1) \cup \left\{ \left.\begin{pmatrix}0 &b\cr b^{-1} &0 \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \right| b>0 \right\}.\tag{6} $$
   The closed convex cone
   $$ \overline{{\rm Convcone}(O^+(1,1))}~=~{\cal V} \tag{7}$$
   of $O^+(1,1)$ is OP's set (2).

Comment: So the conjecture is that $\cal V$ is made of all convex combinations of elements $\lambda \Lambda$ where $\lambda \geq 0$ and $\Lambda \in O^+(3,1)$. Yesterday I had the same idea, but I was not able to prove it. It does not seem a trivial proof. (Finding a counterexample sounds equally difficult.)

Comment: I also suspect that $\partial V$ is just made of the matrices $\lambda \Lambda$ where $\lambda \geq 0$ and $\Lambda \in O^+(3,1)$.

Comment: Notes for later: $\quad SO(1,1)=\left\{ \left.\begin{pmatrix}a &0\cr 0 &a^{-1} \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \right| a\neq 0 \right\}$; $\quad O(1,1)=SO(1,1) \cup \begin{pmatrix}0 &1\cr 1 &0 \end{pmatrix} SO(1,1)$;  $\quad SO(2)=\left\{ \left.\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &\sin\theta\cr -\sin\theta &\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \right| \theta\in\mathbb{R} \right\}\cong U(1)$; $\quad O(2)=SO(2)\cup \begin{pmatrix}1 &0\cr0 &-1 \end{pmatrix} SO(2)$;

Comment: Notes for later: $\quad x^{\pm}=\frac{t\pm x}{\sqrt{2}}$; $\quad ds^2= -dt^2+dx^2= -2dx^+dx^-$; $\quad \frac{\partial x^{\pm}}{\partial(t,x)}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 &1\cr 1 &-1 \end{pmatrix}= \frac{\partial(t,x)}{\partial x^{\pm}}$; $\quad T:\quad t\to -t,\quad x\to x, \quad x^{\pm}\to - x^{\mp}$; $\quad P:\quad t\to t,\quad x\to -x, \quad x^{\pm}\to  x^{\mp}$; $\quad T=-P$;